# How to change checkbox text in checkboxlist? I tried but got error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, checkbox

I work on windows application. It has one form in application which displays `check boxes` in `check box list`, here is the screen shot of form

[image: My windows form]

It's single from of my application which i display in different languages And also my windows application is made in multiple languages Like English, German, Japanese etc..

My problem is that `how to display translated text of check box in check box list`

Here is my code :

```
  this.checkedListBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Select All",
        "Amplitude1",
        "Amplitude2",
        "Amplitude3",
        "Amplitude4",
        "Amplitude5",
        "Amplitude6",
        "Amplitude7"});
        this.checkedListBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 55);
        this.checkedListBox1.Name = "checkedListBox1";
        this.checkedListBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 124);
        this.checkedListBox1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ckbselectall_CheckedChanged);
```

I made a single file to translate text of form, i put that code below where `LCheckBox` is my file from where i translate the text of check box in check box list

```
  this.checkedListBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        LCheckBox.SELECTALL,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude1,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude2,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude3,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude4,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude5,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude6,
        LCheckBox.Amplitude7});
        this.checkedListBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 55);
        this.checkedListBox1.Name = "checkedListBox1";
        this.checkedListBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(123, 124);
        this.checkedListBox1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ckbselectall_CheckedChanged);
```

But it gives me some error message

Comment: Edit your question with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask for the language at the begining and then create the checkbox list depending on the language. u can use different if cases for each language

Comment: it's just one form of my application which display in different languages.

Comment: i am not sure if i get your question correctly but i created a code block for you. i will post it in new answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In code I just use the items collection to modify the desired item.

So lets say you have a form with a button on it. When the button is clicked
you want to add one to all the items in the list, then the code to do that
would look as found below assuming that the listbox was named "_list" and
the button was named "_button."

```
private void FillList()
{
    _list.BeginUpdate();
    _list.Items.Clear();

    for(int i =0 ; i <=9; i++)
        _list.Items.Add(i);

    _list.EndUpdate();
}

private void _button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _list.BeginUpdate();

    ListBox.ObjectCollection items = _list.Items;
    int count = items.Count;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int integerListItem = (int)items[i];
        integerListItem ++;
        // --- Update The Item
        items[i] = integerListItem;
    }

    _list.EndUpdate();
}
```